# Azure Function .NET Core CompleteAsync in separate HTTP call

Tags: .net, azure-functions, azureservicebus, messaging, amqp

I have following use-case with Azure Service Bus (ASB):

- I need to push and pull messages to Azure Functions over HTTP 
  *(I know one can use WSS for AMQP, but I'm not allowed to use this unfortunatelly)*

  - it is only allowed to make requests from the system where messages needs to be published to/consumed from ASB, there is no option to push back from an Azure Function
  - processing the messages may fail and therefore there MUST be an option to commit successfully processed messages (f.e. the idea here was to "complete" those messages by providing the lock)
- Function where payload gets pushed just gets a batch of messages and publishes them to ASB (this works absolutelly fine)
- Function where the pull happens has some issues however, this is described below

Consumer function:

```
[FunctionName("Consumer")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest request,
    ILogger log)
{
    ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder builder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString){
        TransportType = TransportType.Amqp,
        EntityPath = EntityNameHelper.FormatSubscriptionPath(topicName, subscriptionName)
    };
    MessageReceiver receiver = new MessageReceiver(builder);

    var methodType = request.Method;
    switch (methodType)
    {
        case {} when methodType.Equals(HttpMethods.Get):
            IList<Message> receivedMessage = await receiver.ReceiveAsync(batchSize, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(operationTimeout));

            IList<Payload> payloads = new List<Payload>();
        
            foreach (var m in receivedMessage ?? Enumerable.Empty<Message>())
            {
                Payload p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Payload>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m.Body));
                p.Lock = m.SystemProperties.LockToken;
                payloads.Add(p);
                }
        
                return new OkObjectResult(payloads);
            
        case {} when methodType.Equals(HttpMethods.Post):
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            List<string> messageLocks = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(requestBody);
                
            messageLocks.ForEach(async l =>
            {
                // Due to different ClientID this part will throw an exception (see below)
                await receiver.CompleteAsync(l);
            });
                
            return new OkResult();
    }

    return new BadRequestResult();
}
```

When I call the function (Get) it returns messages (with the lock) as expected. But when I try to "complete" those locks by invoking the function again (Post with locks provided) I get following exception:

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessageLockLostException: The lock supplied is invalid. Either the lock expired, or the message has already been removed from the queue, or was received by a different receiver instance.
```

I know that each function invokation results in a different ClientID generated. But is there any option (using SubscriptionClient or anything else) to achieve what I need here?

Main reason for performing two calls is that messages are processed when pulled and it can happen that the processing part just crashes or it is simply not guaranteed that those messages gets processed when pulled so there needs to be an additional call to "complete" those message when they (or only a subset of messages) are processed by the pulling side.

Comment: I'm sorry but your design just doesn't look or feel right to me. You have one HTTP-triggered Function that does two very different things: a) Post messages to a service bus (that part is ok) and b) on GET requests fetch messages from the very same SB. As a very first thing: can you separate those into two Functions? Plus, the pattern for doing b) in the first place you have to explain

Comment: @silent function above only consumes and tries to "complete" from ASB. It never publishes any messages, this is achieved by a separate function (did not publish as it is a straightforward one). Retrieving messages works as expected with the function above but my main problem is I have to "commit" them after they are processed by the pulling party which is not possible with the code above as the ClientId changes and thats the problem (as I understand). Hope I was able to discribe it somehow :)

Comment: @silent Sure thing I can deploy two different functions for "consuming without completing" and "complete only" but the behaviour will not change I guess, And, well, this use-case seems to make little sense, but it's the only option I can implement as the pulling party does not allow any pushing from outside (would be easier of course).